# Moving boot volume to new disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot

I'm about to move / to a new disk.  I intend to do something like the accepted answer to [this question](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/31534/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-larger-hard-drive/) which recommends booting to a liveCD.  All of the how-to documents I see online recommend booting to a liveCD.

Is booting to a liveCD strictly necessary?  What would make it necessary to boot from a liveCD rather than the currently running system that is getting a new boot disk?

Answer (score 0):

I thought using a live iso system would make it easier to copy your old system, if it were not in use there wouldn't be problems with unmounting `/`, or with having different partitions with different data all being mounted while running, so even a raw partition copy with `dd` would be easy.

The question you mention just mounts one `/` partition and copies it to another partition... I would give it a try while running the system normally & just copy the files to another partition & see if it works. The worst that can happen is it won't work & you'll have to do it from a live iso anyway. You'll need to set up / configure grub for the new disk, but that's probably the same whether running live or not, since you're not `dd`'ing the whole disk anyway.